# What does single `position: absolute` do to a <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

I've a simple, silly question. What does `position: absolute` do to a `div` tag?

Here's an example. Let's say I've three `<div>` tags:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" style="position: absolute"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

From my experiments `position: absolute` somehow "pushes" `#b` outside of regular block element flow and it appears between `#a` and `#c`, with `#a` directly following `#c` and `#b` just floating there below or above them.

What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, `position: absolute` completely removes the element from normal layout flow, leaving you free to position it wherever you want.

Comment: I think he's asking how it works when `top`, `left`, `bottom` nor `right` are not specified.

Comment: Actually this answer is what I was looking for. I think. So it removes element from normal layout flow, and I can position where I want it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position allows you to test the different attributes.

Comment: @bodacydo - if this answer is what you're looking for, how about accepting and maybe upvoting?

Answer (score 2):

The `position` attribute controls the location based on which ever parent element has a `position` defined. Unless a value is set explicitly for an element on the page the first parent with `position` is the `<body>` element.

Once you set a `position` value for an element you can then place elements within it.

As a rule I always set the nearest parent to have `position: relative` which is essentially the normal position it would have. Then I can position elements within it.

`position: absolute` will place the element using co-ordinates based on the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` attribute values.

Comment: Longer reader with examples but covers the details; http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `position:absolute;` property to `block b`, you basically ripped that div div out of the layout's flow. The absolute div (block b) ignores it's next neighboring element(s) in the layout and vice versa.

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/12/ `block C` is positioned right after `block A` as though `block B` doesn't exist. In the same way, `block B` ignore `block C` and position itself next to A.

> An element with **position: absolute;** is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS positioning, you can place an element exactly where you want it on your page.

When you are going to use CSS positioning, the first thing you need to do is use the CSS property position to tell the browser if you're going to use absolute or relative positioning.

Both Postion are having different features.In Css Once you set Position then you can able to use top,right,bottom,left attributes.

**Absolute Position**

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

**Relative Position**

A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.

To position an element relatively, the property position is set as relative. The difference between absolute and relative positioning is how the position is being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Positioning schemes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme),

> In CSS 2.1, a box may be laid out according to three positioning
>   schemes:
>
> - [Normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow).
> - [Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).
> - [Absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning).

Therefore, adding `psotion: absolute` to your element will make it positioned according to the absolute scheme, instead of the normal flow one.

According to [The `position` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position), `position: absolute` means this:

> The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the
>   [`top`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-top), [`right`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-right), [`bottom`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-bottom), and [`left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-left) properties.
>   These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's [containing
>   block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block).
>
> Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This
>   means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings.
>
> Also, though [absolutely positioned](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned) boxes have margins, they do
>   not [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) with any other margins.

Also, according to [Absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning),

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with
>   respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow
>   entirely (it has no impact on later siblings).
>
> An absolutely positioned box establishes a new containing block for
>   normal flow children and absolutely (but not fixed) positioned
>   descendants.
>
> However, the contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow
>   around any other boxes.
>
> They may obscure the contents of another box (or be obscured
>   themselves), depending on the [stack levels](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#stack-level) of the overlapping
>   boxes.

Absolutely positioning is related to `display` and `float`, as explained in [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). Basically,

- An absolutely positioned box is not floated
- An absolutely positioned box is blockified as follows: a display of `inline-table` becomes `table`; and `inline`, `table-row-group`, `table-column`, `table-column-group`, `table-header-group`, `table-footer-group`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, `table-caption`, `inline-block` become `block`

According to [Layered presentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers), absolutely positioned elements are painted in another layer:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

The position (and the size, if `width` or `height` are `auto`) of an absolutely positioned element is determined by its containing block and its `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties. If those are not specified, their value will be `auto`. The algorithms are explained in detail [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height). Basically:

- The element will be placed at the same position it would have if it had `position: static` and `float: none`.
- An `auto` width is calculated by shrink-to-fit: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).
- An `auto` height is calculated [as usual for block formatting context roots](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#root-height)